# Prevent page refresh when submitting Django form

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there any way to stop refreshing of the form page after hitting submit button?

I am looking for doing this in front end using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by the following:

```
var formImage = $("#form_image");
formImage.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (msg, status, jqXHR) {
            console.log(msg);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(jqXHR);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. jQuery Ajax is good idea

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
var form = $("#form").serialize();
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"{% url 'url to view' %}",
data: form,
success:function(data){
// Something success
},
error:function(data){
//When error occurred
},
});
});
});
```